# We couldn't find anything for nutri-score - Is a discussion about nutri-score off-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'd rather ask here than post the question and have it closed.

There are no results to a search for nutri-score. I have just moved out of home and am starting my first attempts at cooking.

Is this question acceptable or how do I need to rephrase it? Is warm up ready-made products already cooking?

> I base a lot of my food purchases on nutri-score (how healthy it is).
> I was very surprised to see that a frozen pizza has a nutri-score B. I
> always thought frozen pizzas and frozen foods in general were
> unhealthy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SA!

Indeed, it is off-topic.  [Per On-Topic list](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Please note that the following subjects are considered off-topic here:

> General health and diet issue (e.g. "Is cauliflower healthy?")

The folks who answer questions on SA are not nutritionists, doctors, or officials in food regulatory agencies.  We're amateur cooks, as a rule.  As such, you question is an excellent example of "questions we couldn't answer adequately if we allowed them."

When it comes to nutrition, we can take and answer questions like "If I'm a French chef, what are the requirements for nutri-score labelling" because that's a regulation someone can point to in an answer.  But: "Why does nutri-score rate food X as Y" strays into the territory of both nutrition science and politics, and the answers you would get would be essentially speculation -- and ultimately, StackExchange sites need to have determinative answers to questions.